# assembly reference error after pulling source code for asp.net mvc app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, version-control, nuget-package

I am new to working with NuGet and the world of numerous third party assemblies. I have always thought that when you pull from source code, you should be able to build your solution with no errors (which, it seems to me now, is only possible if you put your 3rd party binaries in source control, but that could cause a lot of bloat in your repo if you're using a lot of versions, but maybe I'm wrong on that).

**My Situation:**

So I downloaded a visual studio solution from source control and I have all these bad references in the 2 projects because the 3rd party dlls are not on my machine (eg, when I built the solution I got about 800 of these sorts of errors: "**The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**). NuGet shows that they are installed and their versions, based on the packages.config, I think?, but it doesn't give me the option to get a specific version or, preferably, a button like "just get me all the correct crap I need". However, I noticed NuGet does have an "update all" option, which would get the latest 3rd party versions online. I did this and it fixed the references, but then gave me a runtime error when I ran the app. Specifically, I got the error **"could not load file or assembly 'xxxx' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".**

The only thing I can think of is to uninstall from NuGet, then install the exact version I see in packages.config via command line (eg: "install-package 3rdpartydll -version 2.0.0.1") for *each one*.

So I ask, is this really what you have to do? I'd have to do this with like 25+ libraries. And then every new dev who gets source code would have to go through the same stuff.

Or, option 2, just put the dlls in source code so they come down when someone does a pull request?.

Or, option 3, just have a public folder on the network called "3rd party crap" that one would go to to copy all the binaries they need down to their machine (managing it only when new versions were introduced to the app).

**So my question is:** 
Is there a better way to deal with this? I need to start coding and stop dealing with this mess, but I feel I need to understand this, and fix it, so the next person doesn't have to deal with it. Or perhaps I am missing some fundamental knowledge re-all this. Any insight/best practices is appreciated.

Comment: If you right click on your solution file and click restore NuGet packages does that fix your issue?

Comment: Yes Derek, that worked. Is my following understanding correct:

NuGet creates a packages folder for the solution and a packages.config file for each project. When "restore NuGet packages" is enabled, the packages folder and containing libs won't be added to source control. And when you pull down your project, VS will examine the packages.config file and for each listing, ensure that the correct lib is in the packages folder, and, if not, will download the correct lib into it. 

Also, should my teammates enable this in their solutions? Do we all have to have this enabled?